# Tor browser can not connect

Tags: log

Everything was fine, i was surfing in the Tor Browser witout any problem, until suddenly the browser did not find any pages anymore. So i restarted the browser and then i get this message: TOR FAILED TO ESTABLISH A TOR NETWORK CONNECTION.

Tor log:

3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.500 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\ROCKSTAR\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/29/2018 1:31:40 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/29/2018 1:31:41 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
3/29/2018 1:31:41 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
3/29/2018 1:31:41 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
3/29/2018 1:31:42 AM.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
3/29/2018 1:31:43 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [WARN] Our clock is 13 hours, 28 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2018-03-29 14:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [WARN] Received microdesc flavor consensus with skewed time (CONSENSUS): It seems that our clock is behind by 13 hours, 28 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (Clock skew -48497 in microdesc flavor consensus from CONSENSUS; CLOCK_SKEW; count 1; recommendation warn; host ? at ?) 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2018 1:31:44 AM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

I tried to connect with bridges but it did also not work!

So what is the problem and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our clock is 13 hours, 28 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2018-03-29 14:00:00 UTC). Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!

That line makes me think that your computers clock is out of sync with your local timezone. This can mess things up as the tor software needs an accurate date and time according to the computer it's running on. Make sure your computer's clock is on the correct time and that line should go away.

If your tor browser was working fine before, another thing I'd as is if you made any edits to the TORRC file; if any edits were made to the TORRC file that weren't typed in correctly, this can cause the tor software to crash on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Read the logs you posted.

`[WARN] Our clock is 13 hours, 28 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2018-03-29 14:00:00 UTC). Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!`

Tor needs an accurate date, time, and timezone to work. Most likely you need to accurately set the timezone in your operating system's settings. Then fix the time.

Answer (score 0):

It works now after i changed the time. The time on my pc was totaly wrong. I dont understand though how it happened suddenly while browsing in the tor.

Thanks for the help guys!

By the way, i tried to change the torrc file, i think i made some wrongs. But i deleted Tor and instalel it again. It should be original files now right?